# ImportError: No module named objdem

Tags: python, bash, package

I have a python package that is intended to be used as a command line script.

The file directory of the package (before dist) is:

```
/bin/
    objdem
/objdem/
    __init__.py
    objdem.py       
LICENSE
README.md
requirements.txt
setup.py
```

The `objdem` file contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import objdem
main()
```

And `objdem.py` is the script that I want to run by typing `objdem` on the command line.

Where am I going wrong?

On windows instead of an error it opens the `objdem` file.

EDIT:
You can try it here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/objDEM/1.0.6

EDIT:

`setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='objDEM',
    version='1.0.3',
    description='Generates an .obj file representing a digital elevation map from coordinate input',
    license="MIT",
    author='Kevin Forrest Connors',
    author_email='kevinforrestconnors.com@gmail.com',
    url="https://github.com/kevinforrestconnors/objdem",
    packages=['objDEM'],
    install_requires=['numpy', 'scipy', 'utm'],
    scripts=['bin/objdem']
)
```

Comment: How do you type `objdem` on command line. Please post full command.

Comment: `objdem default` or `objdem min_long min_lat max_long max_lat resolution`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Assuming you package name in `setup.py` is objdem</strike>

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from objDEM import objdem
objDEM.main()
```

your package is named `objDEM` not `objdem`

Running your package worked succesfully for me with the above changes.
`python setup.py install`
`./bin/objdem`

Comment: I got this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/bin/objdem", line 3, in <module>
        from objdem import objdem
    ImportError: No module named objdem

Comment: Can you explain what you mean?  The dependencies in `requirements.txt` are installed when you `pip install`

Comment: can you post your `setup.py`

Comment: I added it to the main post.  Thanks

Comment: @KevinConnors have updated my answer. you need to fix your package name